# write mysql query using inner joins for three tables

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, aliases

I have the following query which works perfectly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contacts 
WHERE id in (

             SELECT DISTINCT contacts.id 
               FROM contacts 
             INNER JOIN contacts2tags 
                ON contacts.id = contacts2tags.contactid 
            WHERE tagid in(7,4)
                 )
```

Here **contacts** table contains id, first_name, last_name, ..and **tags** table contains id, name. **contacts2tags** table contains contactid and tagid which are same as contacts.id and tags.id respectively

Now, what I want is, to display only the contacts which have both a tagid 7 and a tagid 4.
I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contacts
WHERE id IN
    (
     SELECT CT1.contactid 
 FROM
tags T1, contacts2tags CT1, tags T2, contacts2tags CT2
WHERE CT1.contactid = CT2.contactid
 AND CT1.tagid = T1.id
 AND CT2.tagid = T2.id
 AND (T1.id = 7 AND T2.id = 4)
```

and it works too.
My problem is, I want to convert the above second query to one using inner joins.
I have an array of ids stored in $tmp in php
I want to use those ids and write the above query for them.
How do I do that? I am not comfortable with sql. Might be its a very simple thing to ask.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
The answer below solved the problem. But the sql runs very slow for 10k records. Any suggestions to optimise it? Pasting the updated query as given in the answer.

```
    SELECT c.id 
     FROM contacts c
    inner join contacts2tags t on c.id = t.contactid 
    where t.tagid in (7,4)
    group by c.id
    having count(distinct t.tagid) = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT c.id 
FROM contacts c
inner join contacts2tags t on c.id = t.contactid 
where t.tagid in (7,4)
group by c.id
having count(distinct t.tagid) = 2
```

Comment: thanks a lot.it works :) So i can now include all the elements of my array $tmp in in(...) and use the value of sizeof($tmp) ?

Comment: Yes and then you have to adjust the number in the `having` clause too.

Comment: the query runs well in phpMyadmin, but when i do it in my php file, i'm getting the following error:Unknown column 'contacts2tags.tagid' in 'having clause' I don't know why?

Comment: Then you don't use the same query. The error does not match the query. If you use an alias for a table like `t`, then you have to use it instead of the real table name everywhere.

Comment: hello. how can  the above query be optimised further? it worked fine on my local server, but it runs terribly slow on the actual server. I have about 10000 records in the database. thanks!

Comment: Run `explain select ...` to see where no index can be used and add the missing indexes to your table.